# How can I actually execute a 'while True' loop code while there is a 'mainloop()' in the code?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, tkinter-text

I am sorry if my question is not understandable.
**Anyways, I have this code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("My Window")

# Adding a text widget thing.
text = Text(root, foreground='black', background='white', font=("Consolas", 16))
text.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# a while true loop.
while True:
    text.delete(1.0, END)
    text.insert(END, "This is a text in a loop")

# Calling the Python tkinter's mainloop.
root.mainloop()
```

Each time I try to run the code above, it doesn't show the Window, instead, it runs the code in the `while True` loop.

So the main question is, **Is there a way to make Python show the window (I mean execute the code `root.mainloop()`, and then execute the `while True` loop's code?**

Any help or answers would be much appreciated! 
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much for your quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to avoid this, but you can use a recursion loop.

make a function called "myloop" and repeat it, like so, and then call it just before mainloop:

```
def myloop():
   <code>
   root.after(1, myloop) #repeats the function again 1 1000th of a second after it finishes


#----- down by where you're calling mainloop-----


root.after(1, myloop)
root.mainloop()
```